# Urban Airship tags are not updating

Tags: urbanairship.com

Tags are not updating after reopening the app. When first time I build and run app, the tags are working fine and updating but when I kill the app and restart it, then the tags are not updating and push notification receive on previous tags.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer this quide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I assume you are on Android? If so we fixed a bug that sounds familiar to your issue -  https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L16.  Please update to 8.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in previous versions as mentioned by @ralepinski. Updating to `8.3.2` should solve your problem.

Follow this [link](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L16) for more details.